# I want to send a string from an android device to a windows machine over wifi with c#. Is this possible?

Tags: c#, android, database

I want to make a program that transmits strings from an Android device, to the web or directly to my PC.

Do note that the android and windows device are connected to the same wifi if this makes a difference. The problem here is that I do not know how to send strings from one device to another. I am thinking of doing it in a txt file and then reading it with the program on my PC (Which I have already tested), but I don't know how to transmit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can share a data from cross platform devices. There are many methods to do it. I would personally recommend using Web APIs using asp.net core, the consume that Web API in your android application, it can be in Xamarin, and for Desktop you can used HttpClient package to consume either in WPF or Winform.